# Change SSL protocol version while reusing session

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

I'm using `ssl3` to connect to server. When the `-change_session_version` option is specified with the `-reconnect`, I want the session protocol to change to `SSLv2` from `SSLv3`

This is my command: `apps/openssl s_client -connect 10.102.113.3:443 -reconnect -change_session_version -ssl3`

Now, I know that I should have either this code:

```
if(change_session_version)
    s->session->ssl_version = SSL2_VERSION;
```

Or this code:

```
if(change_session_version)
    s->version = SSL2_VERSION;
```

I don't know where to put this code though.

I have declared `change_session_version` as an `int` in `ssl.h` and have set it to `1` if the `-change_session_version` option is specified.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. A 'session' in SSL comprises the protocol, the cipher suite, the key material, and the peer certificates. You can't change any of them without creating a new session.

**EDIT** Just changing a variable in a piece of local memory can't possibly accomplish anything useful. The peer won't know about it, and the other peers sharing the session on other connections won't know about it either. You have to re-handshake and negotiate a *new* session.

Comment: Ah, so when you want to reuse a connection, and you attempt to change the `version` just before the reuse happens, the change in the  version of the `SSL` variable is just ignored because communication has already occurred on an already established channel?

Comment: It would be ignored because the *session* already exists, let alone the connection. It would be astonishing if you even had write access to the variable. There is certainly no SSL mechanism for doing anything to an existing session on the wire except refreshing the keys.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. First, SSLv2 is practically not supported anymore and most stacks don't even implement it while the others have disabled it. And then there is no support for session resumption in SSLv2 at all.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to change it to `TLS 1.2` from `SSLv3`? Where would i put this code?

`if(change_session_version)
    s->version = TLS1_2_VERSION;`

Comment: This probably depends on the server implementation. Session tickets are only available since TLS1.0 and it is recommended to encode the protocol version in the ticket. Session Ids are older and it depends on the server what is stored there.  If you just want to try if it works at all you might have a look at the `-sess_out` and `-sess_in` parameters of `s_client` and try to resume the session with another protocol version.

Comment: @RandomlyNamedUser You can't do it at all. It does't make sense. You would be changing it only in your own copy of the session data. The peer won't know anything about it, and neither will any of the other peers sharing the same session. You would have to re-handshake and negotiate a new session.