# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type openSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm using the `openssl` library. In the `apps/s_client.c` file, I am trying to access the `con` variable, which is declared like this:

```
SSL *con=NULL;
con=SSL_new(ctx);
```

However, whenever I try to access any of the members of `con`, for example,
`con->version`, I get this error:

```
s_client.c: In function ‘s_client_main’:
s_client.c:1667: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

What header file should I include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All headers are already included, you just need to remove OPENSSL_NO_SSL_INTERN before ssl.h inclusion.

apps/s_client.c:

```
...
#undef OPENSSL_NO_SSL_INTERN
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was not aware of `OPENSSL_NO_SSL_INTERN`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, I am now able to access the data fields of `con`.

Comment: Any idea how to change the `version` on a `-reconnect`? I'm developing a negative tool that attempts to change the protocol from SSLv3 to TLSv1 after every reconnect. Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556222/change-ssl-protocol-version-while-reusing-session/28556451